# simple captcha field type for meteor autoform

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, captcha, meteor-autoform

I need a simple captcha field type for my form. I used [meteor-autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) for generating form.

**I don't know how to create custom (captcha) field type for auto-form.**

For example how to wrap [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-captcha) node.js module to auto-form add-on.

***I also don't want to use google reCaptcha.***

Please guide me.

Comment: Before I continue looking into this, are you sure you can install [cairo](http://cairographics.org/download/) package onto your server? It's a dependency for that npm package.

Comment: Also, I am not sure the package works as it should. This is what it prints out: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/f3BBa7R.png?1)

Comment: It's just an example. Many packages available in npm repository about captcha generating and I'll accept any of this as answer if working with meteor.

Answer (score 0):

Ok a common issue when building with meteor is figuring out how to include node packages in a meteor project. Here's the way I do it!

1. Install the lovely meteorhacks:npm package which allows for easy node package wrapping.

`meteor add meteorhacks:npm`

2. Edit the packages.json file (which meteorhacks adds to your meteor project root)

The packages.json file should something like this:

```
{
   "node-captcha" : "0.2.1"
}
```

*Note: 0.2.1 is the latest package version of node-captcha which I found on the npm link you supplied.*
Anytime you are including a node package using meteorhacks:npm, you need to list a node package version.

3. node-captcha can now be included in your meteor js files by using the following statement:

`Meteor.npmRequire('node-captcha');`

This should do the trick! Please accept my answer if this is what you are looking for :)

Comment: Thanks for your attention but I know how to add npm package to meteor. I described in question that I don't know how to create custom (captcha) field type for auto-form? How to add simple captcha to autoform?